# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: guests, payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :admin_id, :guest, :depart, :return, :adult, :kid
attr_accessible :guests_attributes, :payments_attributes
has_many :guests, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :admin
accepts_nested_attributes_for :guests 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments

end
```

In controller

```
class PaymentController < ApplicationController

def new

@offer=Offer.new
@guest = @offer.guests.build
@payment=@offer.payments.build

end
```

I added guests_attributes, payments_attributes in model.Still i get this error.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Show us your form please.

Comment: guests and payments != guests_attributes and payments_attributes.

Comment: <%=f.fields_for :payments do |payment| %>
Cardtype <%=payment.select :card_type,options_for_select([['Visa','Visa'],'Mastercard','Mastercard'],['Amex','Amex'],['Maestro','Maestro'],['Delta','Delta'],['Laser','Laser']]),{},{:class=>'my_title'}%><%end%>
    <%= f.fields_for :guests do |guest| %>
                          
                               Title

                               <%=guest.text_field :title,:size=>'30%',:max_length=>'255'%>

                              Given Name
                                <%=guest.text_field :first_name,:size=>'30%',:max_length=>'255'%> <%end%>

Comment: Are you using `<%= form_for @offer `? If yes then there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your form or JSON/XML are sending the nested objects with the keys `guests` and `payments`, but they need to be `guests_attributes` and `payments_attributes`.  It looks like the model is configured correctly, though.

This [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) may be helpful.

Comment: yes i followed the railscasts.but don't know where the error occurs

Comment: I want to remove mass protection totally how to do this?I am using rails 3.2.7

Comment: If you want to completely avoid mass-assignment protection for this action, you can try `without_protection` in your controller code.  Something like `@offer.create(params[:offer], {:without_protection => true})`.  However, you should note that mass-assignment is now whitelist-based by default, because there can be security concerns.